# access to digiscan window fields by scripting

Tags: dm-script

is it possible to get the values in the digiscan window in an online
microscope by scripting, 
e.g. the pixel time and image size? There is no such command in the
digiscan command reference at least. If so, would there exist some
more general command like "getgadgetpanel()" and "setgadgetpanelfied()"?
If this would not work there are also the the persistent tags in the global
tags structure. Would it be possible to use these? I mean are these values
updated when the user changes the values in the digiscan window?
Also the fields in the spectrum imaging window would be nice to access!

Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Generally, there are no script commands to access UI elements.**

For the **DigiScan** you can instead get to the parameter-sets and read values from them. (The UI changes the parameter-set.) There is an example for that in the help-documentation (*Example 5: Getting information from existing parameter sets*).

For STEM SI there *do* exist UI-related commands. The scripting SI help-documentation describes them in detail with examples:

[image]